# Quantum efficiency of Photoelectric effect

Tags: photoelectric-effect

What is the typically measured quantum efficiency of photoelectric effect experiments involving ultra violet photons incident upon common metals like copper or aluminum. In case I'm not being clear, what I mean to ask is how many electrons are ejected per photon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of electrons ejected per photon is around $10^{-6}$ to $10^{-5}$ depending on the metal.

The quantum efficiency for the initial creation of the photoelectron is around 0.1 to 1. This is the process used in photomultiplier tubes, and the high quantum efficiency is responsible for the very high sensitivity of PMTs. The trouble is that the photoelectron is travelling in the same direction as the incident light ray i.e. down into the bulk of the metal. We only see an electron ejected from the metal surface if the initial photoelectron is backscattered, or if it can scatter off other electrons and transfer enough energy to them to allow them to escape the metal surface. This process has a low probability, which is why the overall quantum yield is so low.

Incidentally, photomultiplier tubes use a thin metal film and the initial photoelectron travels right through the film and escapes from the other side of the film.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my very first question on here! That was exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: @John Do you have or know of a formula for quantum efficiency for the photoelectric effect? From reading this post I see that quantum efficiency is the ratio of the number of (photo)electrons liberated per incident photon (so QE is a dimensionless ratio). But I want to be more formal about this, and relate the measurable photocurrent to the photon energy. Any recommendations or links? Regards.